# Calling parent class method in callback method of child class

Tags: javascript

I have two classes and class B extends class A. In Class B I am doing some canvas operation and thus need to invoke a callback for image loading. In the callback I want to call the same a method of the parent class. However if I put this line of code into the callback I get a syntax error "Uncaught SyntaxError: 'super' keyword unexpected here". Any idea how I can make the context available in the callback so that I can call the method of the parent class?

Cheers Tom

```
class A{
    super(){
    }

    myMethod(){
        console.log("mymethod of A");
    }
}



class B extends A{
    constructor(){
        super();
    }


    myMethod(){

    var canvas = window.document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        context.canvas.width = 200;
        context.canvas.height = 100;
        context.fillStyle = "#ffff00";
        context.font = "15px Arial";

        context.fillText("Hello World!", 0, context.canvas.height);
        var image = document.createElement("img");
        image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        this.img = image;

        image.onload = async function(){
            super.myMethod();// having thise line in the code results in "Uncaught SyntaxError: 'super' keyword unexpected here"
            console.log("callback");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could try -> `image.onload = async () => {  super.myMethod(); }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) here, which preserves `this` and `super` of the method in which it is defined:

```
myMethod(){
    …
    image.onload = () => {
        super.myMethod();
    };
}
```

Notice that there's no reason to make an event handler `async`.